# Firebase Swift childByAutoId()

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

According to the [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data), `childByAutoId` should generate a unique id whenever it's called.

Ok, but I'm using it here like this:

```
let DeviceInfo = [
                        "ImageUrl":profileImageUrl!,
                        "DeviceName":self.DeviceName.text!,
                        "Description":self.Description.text!,
                        "Category":self.itemSelected
                        ] as [String : Any]

                    self.ref.child("Devices").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapShot) in
                        if snapShot.exists(){
                            let numberOfDevicesAlreadyInTheDB = snapShot.childrenCount
                            if numberOfDevicesAlreadyInTheDB < 3{
                                let newDevice = String("Device\(numberOfDevicesAlreadyInTheDB+1)")
                                let userDeviceRef = self.ref.child("Devices").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)
                                userDeviceRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(userDevices) in
                                    if let userDeviceDict = userDevices.value as? NSMutableDictionary{

                                        userDeviceDict.setObject(DeviceInfo,forKey: newDevice as! NSCopying)

                                        userDeviceRef.setValue(userDeviceDict)
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                            else{
                                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry", message:"You can only add three devices", preferredStyle: .alert)
                                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { _ in })
                                self.present(alert, animated: true){}

                            }
                        }else{
                            self.ref.child("Devices").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).setValue(["Device1" : DeviceInfo])


                            self.ref.child("UserDevices").childByAutoId().setValue([
                                "ImageUrl":profileImageUrl!,
                                "DeviceName":self.DeviceName.text!,
                                "Description":self.Description.text!,
                                "Category":self.itemSelected,
                                "name": self.globalUserName,
                                "email":self.globalEmail ,
                                "city": self.globalCity,
                                "phone": self.globalPhone
                                ] as [String : Any])

                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Great", message:"Device has beed added succssfully", preferredStyle: .alert)
                            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { _ in })
                            self.present(alert, animated: true){}
                                                       }
                    })

                    //
                } })
        }
```

This is a part of a button for adding a device to Firebase.

If there are less than 3 devices, the user can add (*else case here*), otherwise, an alert should appear to the user (*you can add only 3 devices*) 'if case before this else'.

When I added the first device, the two above dictionaries have been added to Firebase. But the second time, when I tried to add the second device, the first dictionary has been added, but not the second one that contains the `childByAutoId`.

That sounds weird for me. Can `childByAutoId` give one id for each register user?

Comment: I'm not asking how to add a limit!

Comment: I'm asking why childByAutoId() did not generate an auto id the second time I added a device?

Comment: Anyone, can give me any suggestion? please.

Comment: Is this could be a bug on firebase itself! Please! Can anyone tell me why childByAutoId() could not generate a random id the second time!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm asking why childByAutoId() did not generate an auto id the second
>   time I added a device?

It looks like you're only calling `childByAutoId()` when "Devices" is empty (i.e. when `snapShot.exists()` returns false). Once you've populated "Devices", that line will not get hit again.

Answer (score 0):

While adding first device, you will fall into `else` condition of `snapShot.exists()` but while adding 2nd and 3rd device, your `snapShot.exists()` condition will `true`. So you need to add 2nd and 3rd **UserDevices** entry in if condition block as well. So you just need to update the few line of code as below:

```
if numberOfDevicesAlreadyInTheDB < 3 {
     let newDevice = String("Device\(numberOfDevicesAlreadyInTheDB+1)")
     let userDeviceRef = self.ref.child("Devices").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid) 
     userDeviceRef.updateChildValues([newDevice: DeviceInfo])
     // Also you need to log your second/third device entry here
     self.ref.child("UserDevices").childByAutoId().setValue([
                            "ImageUrl":profileImageUrl!,
                            "DeviceName":self.DeviceName.text!,
                            "Description":self.Description.text!,
                            "Category":self.itemSelected,
                            "name": self.globalUserName,
                            "email":self.globalEmail ,
                            "city": self.globalCity,
                            "phone": self.globalPhone
                            ] as [String : Any])
  }
```

Comment: I know it's too late for answer, but it may be helpful for others who will get reach here.